# Css border outside of image width

Tags: html, image, css

I want to keep border outside of image width

Let I have image with `75X75` Now I apply `5 px` border on the image. still it `75X75 px`. border placed inside the image width. But I want border placed outside of image width so total size will be `85X85`

I try this code

```css
img {
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px
}
```

```html
<img src="image.jpg" width="75" height="75" />
```

Comment: Why not just change the image width and height to 85x85?

Comment: You're looking for the `box-sizing` css property, I believe

Comment: @jbutler483 yah you are right. its work. give an answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150519/#propdef-box-sizing) CSS property,

in which sets the value of whether a border is included in the size of said 'box'

it can be set to either: `content-box | padding-box | border-box`

```css
div{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:black;
  border:10px solid gold;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 5px black;
  }
.border-box{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }

html,body{
  height:100%;
  background:#222;
  }
```

```html
<div class="normal"></div>
<div class="border-box"></div>
```

---

*Please also note*

Using inline styling is seen as bad practise, as it can lead to specificality issues further down the line. Wrap your css in a <`style>` tag or go one better and use an external stylesheet for styling purposes.

Comment: I use external css. here use inline css for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img style="height:75px; width:75px; padding:2px; border:2px solid red">
```

Comment: I dont want to use img under a div. Is there any possible way to apply css in img tag

Comment: yes you can use css in img tag. remove inset from your img tag's style attribute. Post your code to jsfiddle and show me what do you want

Comment: Check edited answer, and provide a screenshot of your requirement. So that we can get what do you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b4sr578j/16/)**

```
img {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    outline: 5px solid red
}
```

Updated **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b4sr578j/18/)**

You can use `Border` and `border-radius` itself, and its working as you expected.

```
img {
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    border-radius: 5px
}
```

Comment: good point :). I already use this. but problem is I have to make rounded border by using border-radious.

Comment: provide a screen shot of your requirement.

Comment: and add padding: 2px in GLP's answer, May be thats what you want

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this to your css

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="75" height="75" style="border: 5px solid red; border-radius: 5px;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;" />
```

should do the trick